# Initialize a dynamic array in a constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

The class data_buffer_table has an array of objects of the class data_buffer . 
Here's the constructors for both classes :

```
    data_buffer_table::data_buffer_table(int v_max_nb_data_buffer_elt ) 
    {
      max_nb_data_buffer_elt = v_max_nb_data_buffer_elt ;     
      data_buffer_tab = new data_buffer[max_nb_data_buffer_elt] ; 
    } // constructor of class data_buffer_table

    data_buffer::data_buffer(char * v_periph_id,size_t                 v_max_nb_elements, size_t v_element_size):mbuffer(v_max_nb_elements,  v_element_size)
    {
      strncpy(periph_id,v_periph_id,PERIPH_ID_LEN * sizeof(char)) ; 
      head = new periph_data ; 
      tail = new periph_data ;   
      head = (periph_data*)(buffer);
      tail = (periph_data*)(buffer);
    } // constructor of class data_buffer
```

the problem is that the compiler tell me : no matching function for call to ‘data_buffer::data_buffer()’

how can i fix this error ?

Comment: This is an English-only website. Please make sure that your title (and a sentence or two) in your question body are translated into English!

Comment: Also, please use `std::vector` for arrays, instead of `new`!